# Is it possible to read out the coefficients of linear model instead of training with data in R?

Tags: r, lm

I have the following situation:

I have some data and train some linear model on it (potentially with some interaction terms). I save the coefficients of this model, so other programs than R can also use it.

Is there a way now, some weeks later, to read out my model only from the coefficients?

I would imagine something like

1. step: Create the model

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=c(1,6,8,11,9), z=c(1,2,5,10,3))
lmod <- lm(z~x+y+I(x^2), df)
predict(lmod, newdata = df)
co <- coefficients(lmod)
co
```

This gives the predictions `-0.05  4.45  3.95  8.95  3.70` and the coefficients

```
(Intercept)           x           y      I(x^2) 
     8.8250    -12.9375      2.6250      1.4375
```

I would then save `co` to a text-file or something like that.

2. step: I read out those coefficients and do something like that:

```
fm <- formula(paste("z ~", paste(setdiff(names(co), "(Intercept)"), collapse = " + ")))
model <- lm(formula = fm, data = NULL)
model$coefficients <- co
predict(model, newdata = df)
```

and hope to get meaningful results. This approach does not work however, what would be a good way to do it?

Comment: The predictions would be `8.8250 - 12.9375 * df$x + 2.6250 * df$y + 1.4375 * df$x^2`

Comment: So you would suggest to compute the results using string manipulation and analysation? This seems like a lot of work where things could go wrong. Are you aware of a native method that creates this computation automatically given a formula and coefficients?

Comment: No, I'm showing you how the calculation would go if _all_ you have is the coefficients. Clearly if you were saving this as a text file you would read the data into R and automate the calculation. Of course, it would be better to store the whole model in RDS format as per the answer below, but your question suggests you wanted to just store the coefficients.

Comment: @AllanCameron ITYM `…+ 1.4375 *  (df$x)^2`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    # saving the model
    saveRDS(lmod, file = "model.rda")

    #loading the model
    model_old = readRDS("model.rda")
```

then you will get:

```
model_old
    Call:
    lm(formula = z ~ x + y + I(x^2), data = df)

    Coefficients:
   (Intercept)            x            y       I(x^2)  
         8.825      -12.937        2.625        1.437
```

Comment: My thoughts are that the linear model is not just about coefficients; there are other parameters that might make the model different, such as the standard errors of those coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own class (S3-class, I think) to solve this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=c(1,6,8,11,9), z=c(1,2,5,10,3))
lmod <- lm(z~x+y+I(x^2)+x:y, df)
co <- coefficients(lmod)

create_loaded_model <- function(coeffs, paramToReconstruct){
  loaded_model <- list(
    formula=formula(paste(paramToReconstruct, "~", paste(setdiff(names(coeffs), "(Intercept)"), collapse = " + "))),
    coefficients = coeffs
  )
  class(loaded_model) <- "loaded_lm"
  loaded_model
}

predict.loaded_lm <- function(model, newdata){
  fm <- model$formula
  co <- model$coefficients
  model.matrix.lm(fm, data = newdata, na.action="na.pass") %*% co |> as.numeric()
}
loaded_model <- create_loaded_model(co, "z")
predict(loaded_model, df)
predict(lmod, df)
```

This still has some flaws, like I rely on the fact that the first entry of coeffs is named "(Intercept)", otherwise the model fails, but it is sufficient for my purpose.